# Aligning elements in a centered column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an article with text that's centered on the page and has a width of 910px.

My code for it is:

```
section {
    max-width: 910px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Now for pictures I'd like to add the picture floating left with a description on the right (that is vertically centered):

[image]

I tried the following html:

```
<div class="alignSide">
    <div class="leftRow"></div>
    <div class="middleRow"></div>
    <div class="rightRow"></div>
</div>
```

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/5sueow8o/

But somehow it doesn't work out. The two outer divs are too big. You can see the blue div is not aligned with the upper `<section>`.

Is there a way I could do it with flexbox maybe?

Comment: anyone an idea for a better title? I dont know how to call it

Comment: Please post the complete HTML & CSS you've tried, so we can reproduce the problem you're having. Also, a demo would be helpful (e.g. jsfiddle.net).

Comment: @Michael_B https://jsfiddle.net/5sueow8o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider making these adjustments to your `section` element:

**HTML** (no changes)

**CSS**

```
body {
    display: flex;               /* establish flex container */
    flex-direction: column;      /* stack flex items vertically */
    align-items: center;         /* center flex items horizontally */
}

section {
    max-width: 500px;
}

section img {
    width:100%;
}
```

Now the blue div is perfectly aligned with the `section` div above.

[**Revised Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/5sueow8o/7/)